# Emacs ipython shell error message foreground color setting

Tags: python, emacs, foreground

In my python shell with white background it looks like this:

[image: white text on white background]

As you can see, when there is an error, it's white text on white background. In order to see them, I have to highlight the text. I haven't got any luck finding out what face controls those colors. Anyone has any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in `~\.ipython\ipythonrc` there is this section (About a 1/4 away from the top)

```
# colors - Coloring option for prompts and traceback printouts.

# Currently available schemes: NoColor, Linux, LightBG.

# This option allows coloring the prompts and traceback printouts. This
# requires a terminal which can properly handle color escape sequences. If you
# are having problems with this, use the NoColor scheme (uses no color escapes
# at all).

# The Linux option works well in linux console type environments: dark
# background with light fonts.

# LightBG is similar to Linux but swaps dark/light colors to be more readable
# in light background terminals.

# keep uncommented only the one you want:
colors Linux
#colors LightBG
#colors NoColor
```